# Simple Algebraic Equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive reals such that:
$$
x+\frac{y}{z}=y+\frac{z}{x}=z+\frac{x}{y}=2
$$
Find all possible values of $x$, $y$ and $z$.

P.S. The only answer I got was when $x=y=z=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the cyclic symmetry of the equation(s), we can assume, without loss of generality, that either $0\lt x\le y\le z$ or $0\lt z\le y\le x$.

If $0\lt x\le y\le z$, then ${z\over x}\ge1$, in which case $y+{z\over x}=2$ implies $y\le1$.  But $y\le z$ implies ${y\over z}\le1$, so that $x+{y\over z}=2$ implies $x\ge1$.  Putting these two together, we have $1\le x\le y\le1$, which tells us $x=y=1$.  Finally $z+{x\over y}=2$ with $x=y=1$ tells us $z=1$ as well.

The other case, with $0\lt z\le y\le x$, is handled essentially identically.  In this case, ${z\over x}\ge1$, which implies $y\le1$, after which ${y\over x}\le1$ leads to $z\ge1$, etc.

Comment: Nearly the same solution as mine, I added the 3 equations and used AM-GM inequality to get that x+y+z ≤ 3 and just simple algebraic manipulations leading to x/y ≤ 1, y/z ≤ 1, z/x ≤ 1. Thus x=y=z=1. Thanks anyway :)